# How to run pig scripts from HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to run pig script from the hdfs but it shows error as the file does not exist.

My hdfs Directory

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hdfs dfs -ls /
Found 11 items
drwxrwxrwx   - hdfs     supergroup          0 2016-08-10 14:35 /benchmarks
drwxr-xr-x   - hbase    supergroup          0 2017-08-19 23:51 /hbase
drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera supergroup          0 2017-07-13 04:53 /home
drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera supergroup          0 2017-08-27 07:26 /input
drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera supergroup          0 2017-07-30 14:30 /output
drwxr-xr-x   - solr     solr                0 2016-08-10 14:37 /solr
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera supergroup        273 2017-08-27 11:59 /success.pig
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera supergroup        273 2017-08-27 12:04 /success.script
drwxrwxrwt   - hdfs     supergroup          0 2017-08-27 12:07 /tmp
drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs     supergroup          0 2016-09-28 09:00 /user
drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs     supergroup          0 2016-08-10 14:37 /var
```

Command executed

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ pig -x mapreduce /success.pig
```

Error Message

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
2017-08-27 12:34:39,160 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Apache Pig version 0.12.0-cdh5.8.0 (rexported) compiled Jun 16 2016, 12:40:41
2017-08-27 12:34:39,162 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Logging error messages to: /home/cloudera/pig_1503862479069.log
2017-08-27 12:34:47,079 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.Main - ERROR 2997: Encountered IOException. File /success.pig does not exist
Details at logfile: /home/cloudera/pig_1503862479069.log
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Script should be on local FS

Comment: There are examples of running script from hdfs. If script needs to been on local FS then what's the use of -x mapreduce.

Comment: The input and output data is on HDFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `-f <script location>` option and option value to run script located at HDFS path. But script location need to be absolute path as given in following syntax and example.

```
Syntax: 
pig -f <fs.defaultFS>/<script path in hdfs>

Example: 
pig -f hdfs://Foton/user/root/script.pig
```